# what happens to a deleted image that i used on my webpage?

Tags: blogger

I use some images in my blog on google blogs.

I uploaded them from my desktop to google.
I deleted them from my computer.

What happens to them? Does google keep them somewhere in cloud? since i uploaded them somewhere on google?

What happens if I use url image freely on the web and then this image gets deleted - the url is not valid, so my blog will fail to correctly show this image?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: It's not about SEO. However, it's not about programming either, so it's still offtopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are uploaded to Picasaweb.google.com (Now Google +)

Only you have the power to delete them unless your account is hacked.

Comment: or unless there is a DMCA request against them, which may be the concern here. In which case, stop stealing other people's images!

Comment: this answer is short and answering! thx